# Opencart Multi Store and Subdomain in Plesk

Tags: dns, subdomain, opencart, plesk, multistore

i need to create an open cart site with multi store functionality, the domain is shopoox.com .
I have created a subdomain (uk.shopoox.com) in plesk with the same root folder of shopoox.com (/httpdocs)

[the subdomain uk.shopoox.com has the same root folder of shopoox.com](http://www.shopoox.com/shopoox-subdomain.jpg)

and i have set the parent dns zone in shopoox,com for the subdomain

[the parent zone is set as uk.shopoox.com](http://www.shopoox.com/parent-dns-zone.jpg)

The hosting is set to no webhosting., but the domain is not accessible from Chrome.

I tried also to make an iframe forwarding and the site is displayed but the multistore functionality is not working properly.

I have mod_rewrite enabled, do i need to set something in the .htaccess, maybe?

Anyone knows what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add a filed in the client table in the database for host-url.

After that you have to add client id in the every primary table from where stores details has been fetched.You have add a condition of client in those query.

By this your multi store site will run with a same root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was that i didn't create a dns zone for every subdomain, with the redirect didn't work.